# Clicking a button: disabling and executing the button's handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the Button's Click event, ow can you disable the button, and also call its event handler?

I have tried this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

This doesn't work in IE, Mozilla, or Chrome.

Comment: Please do it on the client side **only**.

Comment: Edit your question to be clear on exactly what you want to happen. The code you've posted here will indeed disable the button when the code returns, along with any other code running in that method.

Comment: Do this via JavaScript - it's much simpler and is based on the client doing the work, not the server (What if 1000/10000/100000 users performed the same action?)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff here

    Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return false;");
    Button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="disableButton(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function disableButton(button)
{
//need to delay a few ms so that the button posts back before being disabled
  var buttonToDisable = button;
  setTimeout("reallyDisableButton()"), 2);
}

function reallyDisableButton()
{
  buttonToDisable.disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

I assume that your problem is that people are clicking a button several times (because the page it taking a while to load), thus kicking off the event several times and you only want them to be able to do it once.  This will disable the button after it posts back preventing accidentally sending multiple concurrent postbacks.

Comment: ... or to do away with the need for the delay, you could disable the button first, then call `__doPostBack('Button1','');` yourself followed by `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the original posting back.

Comment: @Scott It's not like the user will see the delay; it appears instantaneous to them.

Comment: I understand that. Simply saying that I like control of when things fire.  Leaving it to a delay to allow the function to complete for the default mechanism to fire the postback, isn't the most controlled solution. I would feel better controlling it myself so that it will fire the postback and and do away with the default functionality because I told it to.  Again, it's just a control preference thing.